# 0x00000f booting windows after installing arch

Tags: windows, windows-10, mbr

After installing Arch, Windows didn't appear in the GRUB 2 menu. So I added it manually, but after trying to choose Windows from the menu I got a 0x000000f error from Windows.

My Windows 10 and Arch Linux are both booted using BIOS Legacy (No EFI).

What I tried so far:

- Running "Start-up Repair" from a Windows 10 Installation USB, but it keeps telling "start-up repair couldn't repair your PC""
- running `bootrec /fixmbr` which returns a successful response.
- running `bootrec /fixboot` which returns "Element not found"
- running `bootrec /RebuildBcd` which does find the correct Windows but after making a choice for "Add installation to boot list?" it returns "Element not found"
- I tried assigning the right partition (with windows installed) to a station letter (Q) and tried running `bcdboot Q:\Windows /s E:` (Where E: is the system reserved partition, which should be the correct one if I understood correctly) which does return a "boot files sucessfully created" message.

I tried starting `chkdsk` which returned no errors.

So no luck so far.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to `0xC000000F`? Did you rebuild the Grub config after running `bcdboot`?

Comment: Oops, yeah I am referring to `0xC000000F`. Uhm I haven't tried rebuilding the config after the successfully executed `bcdboot` command. I can do that right now, not sure if it does find Windows this time....

Comment: @DanielB You sir, are legendary! Rebuilding my config worked. Windows 10 wasn't recognized, again...! But this time, after manually adding it to my grub file it actually booted! No issues. In fact, I am writing this from my Windows system as we speak. You may enter your comment as Answer so I can mark it tomorrow, if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error 0xC000000F means Windows Boot Manager was unable to read the BCD store (Boot Configuration Data). However it may have been lost/become corrupted, doesn’t matter. With `bcdboot` you already discovered the magic healing tool. Whether you chose the correct partition to place the boot data, who knows.

In case you changed something about where the Windows Boot Manager resides, you should regenerate the Grub configuration using `grub-mkconfig` (sometimes `grub2-mkconfig`).

Discovering Windows using `grub-mkconfig` requires `os-prober`, which may be missing. `os-prober` needs to access partitions to inspect files, which may require the appropriate Grub modules (for `grub-mount`) or kernel modules (FUSE for `grub-mount` or others for regular `mount`).